# Problem with multiple controllers in OMNeT++ SDN

Tags: windows, omnet++, sdn

I'm trying to build multiple controllers. The original code that connect all switches to one controller is as follows:

```
void OFA_switch::connect()
       {
           socket.renewSocket();
           int connectPort = par("connectPort");
       /*
           const char *connectAddress= par("connectAddress");

           EV << "connectAddress  = " << connectAddress << " connectPort            =" << connectPort << endl;

              if (getParentModule()->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("controller") != NULL)
              {
         // multiple controllers; full path is needed for connect address
                  connectAddress = (getParentModule()->getParentModule())->getSubmodule("controller")->getFullPath().c_str();
          cModule *ctl = getSystemModule()->getSubmodule("controller");
        if(ctl != NULL) {
          EV << "ctl->getFullPath() = " << ctl->getFullPath().c_str() << endl;
          connectAddress = ctl->getFullPath().c_str();
       }
         EV << "After: connectAddress  = " << connectAddress << endl;
}

       */
              L3Address ctlIPAddr;
                EV << "connect L3Address  = " <<               L3AddressResolver().tryResolve("controller", ctlIPAddr) << endl;

      //    EV << "result: connectAddress  = " << ctlIPAddr << endl;
      //    socket.connect(L3AddressResolver().resolve(connectAddress), connectPort);
            socket.connect(ctlIPAddr, connectPort);

          }
```

---

I'm trying to make some switches connected to `controller1` while the other switches connected to `controller2`, so I tried to adapt the following code to:

```
void My_OFA_switch::connect() {
  socket.renewSocket();
  int connectPort = par("connectPort");

  const char *connectAddress = par("connectAddress");
  EV << "connectAddress  = " << connectAddress << " connectPort =" << connectPort << endl;

  const char *connectAddr;
  cModule *ctl;

  if (strcmp (connectAddress, "controller1")==0)
     {  connectAddr = (getParentModule())->getSubmodule("controller1")->getFullPath().c_str();
       ctl = getSystemModule()->getSubmodule("controller1");
      }
  else if (strcmp (connectAddress, "controller2")==0)
      {  connectAddr = (getParentModule())->getSubmodule("controller2")->getFullPath().c_str();
          ctl = getSystemModule()->getSubmodule("controller2");
      }
  if(ctl != NULL) {
    EV << "ctl->getFullPath() = " << ctl->getFullPath().c_str() << endl;
    connectAddr = ctl->getFullPath().c_str();
  }

  L3Address ctlIPAddr;
  EV << "connect L3Address  = " << L3AddressResolver().tryResolve(connectAddr, ctlIPAddr) << endl;
   socket.connect(ctlIPAddr, connectPort);
 }
```

---

Also, there is a file **Switch.cc** which represents the controller behavior
"in ini file :
*.controller.behavior = "Switch" "that contain:

```
void Switch::initialize() { 
               cModule *ITModule = 
            getParentModule()->getSubmodule("ofa_controller"); 
            controller = check_and_cast<OFA_controller *>(ITModule); 
            getParentModule()->subscribe("PacketIn",this); }
```

Should I change something here?

But when I run it the following runtime error appears and immediately close the simulation:

> Simulation run has encountered a problem. Finished with error.

And in console it appeared:

> Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819
> Working directory: D:/omnet/OpenFlowOmnet/omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.2/myws/openflow/scenarios
> Command line: ../openflow.exe -m -n ..;../../inet/src;../../inet/examples;../../inet/tutorials;../../inet/showcases --image-path=../images;../../inet/images -l ../../inet/src/INET My_2Domain_Ctrl.ini
> Environment variables:
> PATH=;D:/omnet/OpenFlowOmnet/omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.2/myws/inet/src;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\bin;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\usr\bin;;D:/omnet/OpenFlowOmnet/omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.2/ide/jre/bin/server;D:/omnet/OpenFlowOmnet/omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.2/ide/jre/bin;D:/omnet/OpenFlowOmnet/omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.2/ide/jre/lib/amd64;.;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\bin;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\usr\local\bin;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\usr\bin;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\usr\bin\site_perl;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\usr\bin\core_perl;D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2;
> OMNETPP_ROOT=D:/omnet/OpenFlowOmnet/omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.2/
> OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=D:\omnet\OpenFlowOmnet\omnetpp-5.6.2-src-windows\omnetpp-5.6.2\images

I really appreciate any guidance and help because I must do a lot of work and I'm running out of time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSPCe.png)

Answer (score 0):

One has to remember that `strcmp()` returns 0 if the contents of both strings are equal. And in C++ zero means `false`.
So if you want to do something when `connectAddress` is equal to `"controller1"`, you should write:

```
if (strcmp (connectAddress, "controller1") == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Generally, in order to deal with a runtime exception in OMNeT++ do:

1. Set `debug-on-errors=true` in your omnetpp.ini.
2. Build the project in debug mode.
3. Start the simulation in debug (i.e. Run | Debug).

The simulation will stop in the line that causes an error and in the stack trace you may see the referenced calls.

Reference: [Learn OMNeT++ with TicToc - Runtime errors](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/#runtime-errors)

Comment: Thanks for help. I try it but the same issue appears!

Comment: I have extended my answer.

Comment: Thank you for guidance. The debugger refers to this line in SpanningTree.cc   :              nodeInfo[intrand(topo_spanntree.getNumNodes())].isInTree = true;                         Could you please help me to understand it?

Comment: I strongly suggest creating a new question with that problem as well as with [mcve].